# Appmetrics-dash crashes app whenever I issue a postgresql query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using node v7.2.1.

I've installed appmetrics-dash using:
`npm install appmetrics-dash`

In the app, I've added a single line, after the express:

```
var express = require('express');
var dash = require('appmetrics-dash').monitor();
```

My app starts fine, I can see the dashboard at port 3001, but when I issue a query to the (PostgreSQL) database, appmetrics crashes, along with my application:

```
D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\appmetrics-dash\node_modules\appmetrics\probes\postgres-probe.js:54
        if(!client.__appmetricsProbeAttached__) {
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '__appmetricsProbeAttached__' of null
    at D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\appmetrics-dash\node_modules\appmetrics\probes\postgres-probe.js:54:19
    at args.(anonymous function) (D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\appmetrics-dash\node_modules\appmetrics\lib\aspect.js:26:4)
    at D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\pg\lib\pool.js:81:27
    at D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:274:11
    at D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\pg\lib\pool.js:30:28
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:176:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Projekti\a2\app\edgar\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:59:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Comment: Do you use this library correctly according to their documentation? The crash happens in library code, not in the application.

Comment: May you want to consider `dash.attach()` functionality. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics-dash#dashattachoptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading pg to the latest version (6.3.0) fixed the issue, so I guess it wasn't appmetrics fault after all.

Comment: There are many reliability issues in that driver after v5.1, which was the last reliable version.